# How do you represent the number of iterations in the formulation of an optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization

Let's say I want to minimize some function for f(x), with respect to x, in the minimum number of iterations. How would I represent the number of iterations in the formulation of this optimization problem?

If I just want to minimize some function for f(x) with respect to x, I know I can write it out as:

$\min_{x} f(x)$

If I want to minimize that in the minimum number of iterations, could I write it out like this?

$\min_{x} (f(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1)$ where n is the number of iterations

Comment: Perhaps you need to redefine the optimization function then? Have $N(x)$ measure the number of iterations it takes with input $x$ (or potentially $N(x,f(x))$ if you need), and then $\min_x N(x)$.

Comment: I have never tried to optimize such "horribleness". If you have success in such adventure, please, tell the history here then.

Comment: Your objective function will have entries in terms of the input data, which depends on your method. Your objective function value, for each input data, will be the number of iterations. The bad side of this optimization problem is that It is certainly discontinuous, probably continuous on a full measure set and finite number of elements in the image.

Comment: @gt6989b Seems to suggest to put the initial starting point in the input data of your objective function, but this is certainly a bad idea. The least outcome of course is the solution, in the algorithm's view, of the original problem. I would suggest you to read about metaoptimization a bit.

Comment: The number of iterations depends on the method. Why would you try to write it in the problem?

Comment: Sounds like what you're really looking for is hyperparameter tuning, which is essentially optimizing your optimizer parameters. For example, some learning rates will work better than other learning rates when using gradient descent.